# Timezone cause no result from db for current date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I have little problem with time-zone. I have this query:

```
$query =  "SELECT `req_id`,`emp_id`,DATE_FORMAT(`fromdate`,'%m-%d-%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(`todate`,'%m-%d-%Y') FROM `#__vacation` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`fromdate`,'%Y-%m-%d')=CURDATE()";
```

And the problem is whenever I run this query, It shows no result but I have the current date entry on my table. So I want to know, why is that happening?

After a searching for two hour I found that this happens because of the time-zone. So want to know, how can I fetch the correct result while my server has a `EST` time-zone and my time zone is `IST`.

Comment: when you initialize your connection to your database, add a query to issue a time zone change statement. (otherwise place the SET statement before running the above query) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html
don't worry about the timezone tables simple use the format GMT+2 or GMT-4 for example.
---
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SELECT NOW();

Comment: @on_ can you please show me an example for that how can i set the time zone to `EST` before run this query?

Comment: mysql_query('SET time_zone = '-04:00';');

Comment: @on_ how to run both the queries at the same time?

Comment: no you don't need to run them at the same time, simple run the set timezone query before the above query, doing so updates your session variable time_zone, which will affect ANY & ALL queries afterwards.

Comment: @on_ Thanks for Your support. I have solved my problem by changing my query.

Comment: You should submit your answer for others seeking it.